# Possible to find where someone else's website is getting inbound links?

Tags: search-engines, links, backlinks

I know you can do this for websites that you control, but I'm wondering if it's possible to see how someone else's site is linked to?  Preferably for free.

I think it was possible using yahoos search tool in the past but I can't seem to get it to work now.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

[backlinkwatch.com](http://backlinkwatch.com) do this and searching for `link:domain.com` will also show many, but not all, of a given site's links.

Comment: The `site:` operator searches within the site - did you mean the `link:` operator? (it still offers some information, but Google only returns a small subset of actual link data)

Comment: @danlefree good spot mate

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com). it shows the top 100 links to the site

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can spy on competition... But at a cost : http://www.majesticseo.com is the world's biggest links database.

Answer (score 0):

All the YAHOO WebMaster tools have been moved to BING ... So, sign up for Bing webmaster tools and you will have full access to the backlinks data.

Comment: I've looked at Bing webmaster tools, but have not figured out how to find this information about someone else's site.  Can you point me to somewhere that explains how to do this in more detail?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster/